# If I take a car out of the garage, do I need to bring it back?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I've got a few cars in my inventory in the garage, and I'm curious if this is a spawn point, and any time I arrive at the garage I can get a new version of these cars, or is this a storage area (like a real garage) and I lose my car if I don't bring it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to bring your car back to your garage, nor do you need to drive carefully with it. Unlike GTA, your car is permanently saved in your garage and may be taken out as often as needed, even if it is already destroyed or parked somewhere outside.
This means that whenever you decide you need to get rid of a vehicle that's saved in your garage, you'll need to delete it from your garage.

**EDIT** However, if you take a car from your garage to fill a chop shop order (see your Saintsbook under 'car theft'), the car is removed from your garage on completion.

I lost a Vector that way, dammit.